# c# store two vars objects in one var object

Tags: c#

In the past, i was reading data from one excel sheet named "On leave" and do operation on the result like this:

```
var resultNew1 = (from x in dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("On Leave")
                             select x).ToList();
```

but now I have got another sheet which is "Working". so I did this:

```
var resultNew1 = (from x in dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("On Leave")
                             select x);
            var resultNew2 = (from x in dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("Working")
                          select x);
```

please notice that the first one was `ToList()`

but now I didn't make `ToLists()` because I want to ask you if there is a way to store these two vars which are `resultsNew1` and `resultsNew2` in one var and then make that var `ToList()`

If you need more infomration, please tell me

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "and then make that var `ToList()`". Do you want the results of the first followed by the results of the second?

Comment: @JonSkeet so if my question wasn't clear, i meant that I will change the new `var` to list later by using `ToList()`

Comment: Why would you do it later rather than now? Hopefully Selman22's answer is what you want...

Comment: @JonSkeet by later i ment after creating the one var not later as afternoon :) sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List<T>.AddRange`:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.AddRange(resultNew1);
employees.AddRange(resultNew2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Concat`

```
var employees = dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("On Leave")
         .Concat(dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("Working"))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: why did you remove my select statement please? does you answer imply that there is no need for it?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec yes, your select statement is equaivelant to: `dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("On Leave").Select(x => x)` which doesn't do anything. Since Worksheet returns an IEnumerable<T> you can call linq methods direcly.